# By default size of toolbar through material design in android studio

Tags: android

I want to create toolbar in my app, and I am wondering what is the standard height for toolbar in android?

I want it to be big enough for all devices, but not huge. Is there any by default  size of tool bar?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android - Standard height of toolbar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12988011/android-standard-height-of-toolbar)

Comment: `"?attr/actionBarSize"`

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code which uses standard height of toolbar and standard text appearence of the toolbar title.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@color/yellow"
    android:title="@string/title"
    android:titleTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title"
    >
```